# Send push notifications from a queue to Apple's APNs server with PHP 7

Tags: ios, mysql, apple-push-notifications, php-7

So far I managent to register device tokens and create push notification payloads and put them in a apns_messages queue ready to send them to Apple’s push servers.

The last step (sending them to Apple) is something I’m not able to figure out.

So I have a apns_messages table with 2 columns, | devicetoken | payload |

and for example with the following content per row:

```
devicetoken: 24wgh67as7q8h…
payload: {
    "aps": {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
        }
    }
```

This table holds the push notifications I want to send to my users with a php 7 script that I want to run every minute on my server.

According to the documentation from Apple I have to establish a connection with the appropriate APNs (for example the production server: api.push.apple.com:443). In addition, the connection must be authenticated with my provider client certificate, this is a .pem file, I have one.

From the Apple developers website:

> **Best Practices for Managing Connections:** 
> Keep your connections with
>   APNs open across multiple notifications; don’t repeatedly open and
>   close connections. APNs treats rapid connection and disconnection as a
>   denial-of-service attack. You should leave a connection open unless
>   you know it will be idle for an extended period of time—for example,
>   if you only send notifications to your users once a day it is ok to
>   use a new connection each day. You may establish multiple connections
>   to APNs servers. If you need to send a large number of remote
>   notifications, spread them out over connections to several different
>   gateways. This improves performance compared to using a single
>   connection, in that it lets you send the remote notifications faster,
>   and it lets APNs deliver them faster. You may check the health of your
>   connection using an HTTP/2 PING frame.

More details about Apple’s APNs push notification service [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

**In short:**
In PHP 7 how do I setup the right connection? And if there are notifications in the apns_messages  queue how do I send the notifications in the apns_messages table to Apple’s push servers and remove the notification from the apns_messages queue on completion.
(I want to run this this script every minute)